# Writing a function (UDF) in SQL to auto populate Group By Numbers

Tags: javascript, python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

In Snowflake, you can write a UDF to automate many repetitive tasks. One of which I'd like to write a function to is to automatically populate Group By 1,2,3,4,5... columns. Frankly, I am curious why no modern databases do it, cause after all, it should be relatively easy to figure out which column in the result is a dimension and which is an aggregation.

The UDF can be written in Javascript or some other kind of languages.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how I can proceed with this idea?

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality is supported by **dbt macros**. [Using a macro from a package](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros#using-a-macro-from-a-package):

```
select
  field_1,
  field_2,
  field_3,
  field_4,
  field_5,
  count(*)
from my_table
{{ dbt_utils.group_by(5) }}
```

It requires to know how many non-aggregated column exist in advance. More at: [group_by](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/tree/0.8.5/#group_by-source)

---

> *I am curious why no modern databases do it, cause after all, it should be relatively easy to figure out which column in the result is a dimension and which is an aggregation.*

The closest equivalent is `GROUP BY ALL` from DuckDB: [Friendlier SQL with DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/2022/05/04/friendlier-sql.html)

Comment: Any chance a Snowflake function can do that? This is really cool with Group By All.

Comment: @BillyZhao https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas - "GROUP BY ALL"

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent is `GROUP BY ALL`

> [GROUP BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by)
>
> ```
> SELECT ...
> FROM ...
> [ ... ]
> GROUP BY ALL
> [ ... ]
> ```
>
> `GROUP BY ALL`
>
> Specifies that all items in the SELECT list that do not use aggregate functions should be used for grouping.

> [Group By All Columns](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by#label-group-by-all-columns)
>
> The following example is equivalent to the example used in Group By Multiple Columns.
>
> ```
> SELECT state, city, SUM(retail_price * quantity) AS gross_revenue
> FROM sales
> GROUP BY ALL;
> ```